# GDB Debugger cannot use scanf

Tags: gdb

I am using Linux Lubuntu(16.04).

I installed Gdb Debugger with:

```
sudo apt install gdb
```

However,when I try to debug simple program , I always encounter problem
 like this:

[image]

Comment: there is *no* crash here (nor any problem, really).

Comment: @EmployedRussian Well,there is a problem.These C files are at various different locations,and finding them is very difficult job.This shouldn't happen anyways because these files are some stantard C files.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I really need to solve this problem.This is not something that should happen,I know because I used GDB before.You redirected me to some other link,but that doesn't solve anything!

Comment: Before someone can help you solve your problem, you need to explain what the problem **is**. The output you show does not indicate *any* problem and is completely normal, but you probably want to use `next` instead of `step`.